# Field Validations in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to enforce field validations on my Views in the MVC app that I am working on. For example -

- Limit the length of the field to 40
- Ensure only alphanumeric and special characters @#$%&*()-_+][';:?.,! can be entered.

I used the following to restrict the field length:

```
<div>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CompanyName, new { style = "width:300px", maxlength = "40" })%></div>
```

How do I ensure that only alphanumeric and special characters can be entered in the textboxes?

**EDIT:**
I changed the property in my model to

```
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="CompanyName is Required")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 40 characters")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

To test I tried saving a blank CompanyName hoping to get a Server Error since it is Required. However, it saves the blank Company Name. Any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Are you referring to the FluentValidations library? [Integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 3):

This is MVC 2.0 but works just as well for 3.0
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Just look into Data Annotations, and do some Model Validation

EDIT:

your controller action will need something like

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
//success logic
}
//failure logic
//return to view
```

you will also need

```
@Html.ErrorMessageFor(model => model.YourProperty)
```

in order to see the error messages being thrown.

Read the article it does a better job explaining this then anyone else will.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the EDIT to my Q above. It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What it will do is throw errors into the Model State. you then need to Handel the errors thrown. The article will walk you through a full validation scenario.

Comment: I just want to enable the client side validation. I tried what the article said but its not working. I see that I have to reference jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. Where can I download them from?

Comment: Here is the CDN for Microsoft javascript files
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_11
 jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js :
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
 jquery.validate.js : http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js

Answer (score 3):

Just create a ViewModel object like this:

```
class Company
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [RegularExpression(@"someregexhere")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

And bind your View to that model. In this way you'll have both serverside and clientside validation. It's really easy.

```
@model Company

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    Html.EditorFor(x => x.CompanyName)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Oh, this example uses Razor (MVC3), btw MVC2 works pretty much the same as far as I know.

Then just validate the incoming ViewModel in your controller by checking ModelState.IsValid.

Comment: You need to add
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
Id really recommend going completely through the article i posted. It will give you a full understand on how to do validation in MVC.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the EDIT to my Q above. It doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Did you check ModelState.IsValid first? It should be set to false (because you violated the Required constraint therefore rendering the modelstate invalid). In your controller where you receive the filled ViewModel of course.