# Data Validation in MVC not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to perform field validations using the unobtrusive js in my MVC Application.

```
I have the following in the ViewModel:

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="CompanyName is Required")]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 40 characters")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Location" value="Test"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

View:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


<div>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CompanyName, new { style = "width:300px"})%>
        <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor (c=>c.CompanyName) %>
        </div>
```

If I leave the CompanyName blank and try to save the page, I don't see any errors. 
Also, I see the following in the page source:

```
<div>
<input id="CompanyName" maxlength="40" name="CompanyName" style="width:300px" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CompanyName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

**EDIT:**
Here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EmailModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Helper.Save(model);
        return Json(JsonEnvelope.Succes());
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: can u show your httppost action method ?

Comment: Are your inputs in a `form` tag? I don't see any `<form>` or `<% using Html.BeginForm() %>` markup in your code samples.

Comment: @esker : Yes. I didn't paste the entire code

Comment: Probably because it's a double post from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637759/field-validations-in-mvc and it doesn't show much research effort (this stuff can be easily found with google, the answer has already been given multiple times in the previous topic too).

Comment: Please consider giving the people who tried to help you +1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check ModelState.IsValid in your controller. If the state is invalid (thus false), you should return the viewmodel to your view.

Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EmailModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Helper.Save(model);

        return Json(JsonEnvelope.Succes());
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Some other things to check that you didn't mention in your post:

- Make sure you include the JQuery library too, not just the jquery.validate.
- Make sure you placed the input elements inside a form, and the form is set to post

Comment: I am actually returning a JsonResult back. Please see my EDIT above. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I include the jQuery library and all the input elements are inside a form which is set to POST.

Comment: You need to return the EmailModel to the view where it came from when it is invalid. Otherwise you return the JSON to whatever view you like.

Comment: But then I get the error: "Cannot implicitly convert Type System.Web.mvc.ViewResult to System.Web.mvc.jsonresult"

Comment: Yes, that's because your method has a signature that returns JsonResult. You should set that to ActionResult, JsonResult's base class (see my updated example).

Comment: OK. Changing that to ActionResult fixed the error. But when I try to Save now (with blank CompanyName) - I get the view back but no errors?

Comment: According to this article, I should see the data-val="true" in my page source, which I am not getting on the CompanyName field: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Can you try putting Html.EnableClientValidation inside your view? It shouldn't be necessary, but you can try.

Comment: I don't know man :( If you do everything like this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx it just should be working. I can't think of anything that can help any more (besides trying to include JQuery from you own harddisk).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it would sound strange but it worked for me, change the order of Validation lines like this:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] 
[StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 40 characters")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="CompanyName is Required")]
```

or like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="CompanyName is Required")]
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] 
[StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 40 characters")]
```

I don't remember why, i think it's a bug Try and tell us ;)